# Как грамотно работать с шаблонами в django?

Tags: django, шаблоны

Учусь создавать сайты на django и каждый раз одна и та же проблема по какой бы книге я не занимался. Когда дохожу до места, где надо переименовать файл index.html в уже созданный другой html файл и создать новый index.html, то после этого всего код не работает. Как решить этот вопрос? Спасибо за ответ

Comment: *переименовать файл index.html в уже созданный другой html файл и создать новый index.html* - а зачем такие сложные манипуляции?

Comment: А как правильно это делается?